# How to process return value of main() function?

Tags: c++, c

How to process return value of `main()` function on linux or windows?
c/c++

Comment: What do you mean by "process the return value" ?

Comment: Write an OS script that checks the return value of your program.

Comment: Yes, on linux just `./program; echo $?` will output the return value of `program`'s `main()`.

Comment: @iharob ... but only the lowest eight bits of it.

Comment: @zowl true, it's an `unsigned char`, indeed if you return `-1` then `$?` contains `255`...

Comment: A valid question tagged wrong - the programming language is irrelevant.

Comment: For Linux, read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows the process exit code is often a Windows system error code or `HRESULT`, which means that you can retrieve a description (but unfortunately not the C/C++ name, if there is one) via Microsoft's `errlook` utility, which is bundled with Visual Studio.

The process exit code is typically reported by the IDE, or you can access it in a command interpreter as the pseudo environment variable `%errorlevel%` in Windows, or `$?` in Unix-land.

For Windows, if you don't have Visual Studio, e.g. you're using MinGW g++, then you can use this batch file (just put the text in a file with filename extension ".bat") as a poor man's <sup>1</sup>substitute for Microsoft's `errlook`:

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" ("%~f0" %errorlevel%)
powershell -Command "[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]%1" 2>nul
```

In Unix-land, AFAIK about the most you can rely on is that exit code 0 means success, and any other means failure.

---

One way to obtain the C/C++ *name* of a Windows error code used as process exit code, is to simply search the `<winerror.h>` Windows header file. For this it's necessary to convert any negative value to 8-digit hex first. It's not guaranteed, however, that `<winerror.h>` defines a name: many system error codes are defined elsewhere, some don't have names, and the `HRESULT` scheme allows individual applications and libraries to define their own codes.

---

Checking whether a program invocation failed or succeeded depends much on the command interpreter.

With the standard Windows command interpreter ("cmd.exe", which is invoked by C and C++ `system` function):

```
C:\>cmd /c exit 0 && echo Succeeded || echo Failed.
Succeeded

C:\>cmd /c exit 666 && echo Succeeded || echo Failed.
Failed.

C:\>_
```

where "`cmd /c exit N`" is just an arbitrary command (with known exit code N).

In Ubuntu (that's in Unix-land):

```
alf@devubuntu32:~$ which true; which false
/bin/true
/bin/false
alf@devubuntu32:~$ true && echo Succeded || echo Failed
Succeded
alf@devubuntu32:~$ false && echo Succeeded || echo Failed
Failed
alf@devubuntu32:~$ _
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>) Poor man's substitute because `errlook` supports looking for message resources in specified DLLs, and the batch file doesn't.</sup>

Comment: Funny, windows return codes are more descriptive than unix codes (although, both are a programmers choice)